# Can MySql cause a Windows server to shutdown unexpectedly?

Tags: mysql, shutdown

For the 3rd time, my server where my MySQL instance is running simply shutdown unexpectedly, *this time*, causing my tables to be corrupt as I had ALTER statements running.

While in contact with my hosting company, they deny that it is a hardware failure (they have done test that showed no hardware failure) and says that MySQL uses up all resources which causes the server to just shutdown. In my mind, the MySQL instance would shutdown unexpectedly, not the server itself but maybe I'm wrong.

My question is simple. Could MySQL cause the server to shutdown unexpectedly?

There are nothing in the error logs of either the server, or MySQL. Just that the server had shutdown unexpectedly.

Has anyone had this problem where MySQL causes a unexpected server shutdown?

I found that a kernel-power error with event id 41 has been generated all 3 times the error has occured.

```
EventData 

  BugcheckCode 10 
  BugcheckParameter1 0xffffffff49bd9dc9 
  BugcheckParameter2 0x2 
  BugcheckParameter3 0x1 
  BugcheckParameter4 0xfffff80005ed80d8 
  SleepInProgress false 
  PowerButtonTimestamp 0
```

Luckily, **I've managed to find a minidump file,** (only for the first time it happened thought) and I've decoded it to this.

> IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL (a) An attempt was made to access a pageable
>   (or completely invalid) address at an interrupt request level (IRQL)
>   that is too high.  This is usually caused by drivers using improper
>   addresses.

Could this be that I've simply used up all available memory or is there maybe something wrong with the memory itself? I've just sent this details to the hosting company and I am awaiting answer but figured I would get some more opinions.

Comment: it may cause high resource utlization..high swap use ete causing hang of system..what is there in event logs or os logs?

Comment: reboot the server yes, due high resource usage

Comment: Nothing really, just that the server was shutdown unexpectedly. `The previous system shutdown at 5:47:23 on ‎6-‎1-‎2015 was unexpected` Eventid 6008

Comment: @AhmadAbuhasna So that could be both CPU and MEMORY? Where could i find the trace for this?

Comment: @KayNelson if you are using MySQL 5.6.x it will generate out of memory file, and you can check the memory parameters in general by searching for innodb_buffer_size, key_buffer_size inside my.cnf

Comment: @AhmadAbuhasna I am using 5.6, where could i locate this file? my innodb_buffer_pool_size is 45GB of 64GB, key_buffer_size is 64MB as i am not using MyISAM, only innodb.

Comment: @KayNelson regarding the parameters will you please send me the server specification and add the cnf file, regarding the out of memory report check MySQL log file it contain the error as well as the directory for the file under temp for the administrator user,

Comment: I am *extremely* skeptical that MySQL Server is causing Windows to completely shut down without leaving a trace.    If it is, then Windows Server is an even worse platform than I already suspected.  The more likely explanation is that the hosting provider doesn't understand the nature of the problem... therefore, according to them, there is no problem.